# Excel graph: turn stacked bar chart into part bullet chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've a simple data file that has one column of actuals and another of target against categories. I would like to turn the TARGET figure into a 'Bullet marker'. I've seen it done on other graphs but I'm struggling with the category column being overwritten with the xy axis values. Or if I get close to doing it then the xy markers are not central.

I've checked out Peltier but his examples are based on even more comlicated data than mine, so the steps required didn't seem to match up.

Example Data:

```
Cat     Actual    target
A       10        15
B       10        12
C       20        17
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "bullet marker". Can you draw a picture of what you'd like on your chart?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

[image: Bar chart with "bullets" indicating target values]

If so, here's how:

Create a bar chart with both `Actual` and `Target` being two seperate series.

Then select the `Target` series and set the **Chart Type** (of just that series!) to **X-Y Scatter**.

Then format the `Target` series to have *no line* and adjust the visual style, colour and size of the point marker as desired.